# What office suite will be used in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, openoffice.org, libreoffice

Which office suite will be used in Ubuntu 11.04? Open Office or LibreOffice?

Answer (score 8):

Debian and Ubuntu have been using the Go-OO patched version of OOo for quite some time (e.g. the website link for OOo in Software Center points to the Go-OO site), and according to the [Go-OO frontpage](http://go-oo.org/), Go-OO will be discontinued now that there is The Document Foundation / LibreOffice:

> Go-oo joins forces with LibreOffice
>
> Go-oo shares much of its goals and philosophy with The Document
>   Foundation's LibreOffice project, we're therefore supporting LibreOffice
>   since it's inception, and are in the process of merging most of our patches
>   over, as well as migrating to Document Foundation infrastructure. Going
>   forward, the Go-oo project will be discontinued in favor of LibreOffice.

Currently LibreOffice is upstream OOo (= Oracle) + Go-OO patches (mostly Novell) + some other various patches.

So if LibreOffice 3.3 is released in time for Natty, I guess there would be no point in releasing anything else—releasing standard OOo without those patches would result in a serious loss of functionality.  (Of course, if Oracle agrees with that, it could still be named *OpenOffice.org* like now, but I somehow doubt that will happen...)

Answer (score 5):

If I remember a UDS session correctly someone from the Desktop Team told me that LibreOffice will be shipped in Natty.

Answer (score 1):

It is Libreoffice. For more on Libreoffice and Ubuntu, please take a look at the [Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice).

Answer (score 0):

you can read information [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/nattys-default-apps-stay-familiar/)